# Extended Form_validation library in codeigniter, cannot check is field is empty

Tags: validation, codeigniter-3

I was trying to extend codeigniter(3.1.11) form_validation library to add validation rules of my own.
Below is the code written in `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
        // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function snExists($sn){

        if (empty($sn)) {

            $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('snExists', '{field} is required');
            return FALSE;
        }else{

            $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT `sn` FROM `employee` WHERE `sn` = '$sn';");
            $numrows = $query->num_rows();

            if ($numrows > 0) {
                return TRUE;
            }else{
                $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('snExists', '{field} does not exist');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue i am facing is that, when i submit the field empty the validation does not return FALSE.
somehow the `if(empty($sn))` is not satisfied and the `else` is executed.
hope someone could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like codeigniter does not call any validation methods if a field is submitted empty. It will just returns `TRUE` by default. So in my case checking whether `$sn` is empty is pointless.